# Error converting nvarchar to int during INSERT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-insert, type-conversion

I am trying to run the following command:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[PM10100] (VCHRNMBR,CRDTAMNT,DEBITAMT,DSTINDX,...) 
SELECT VCHNMBR,CRDTAMNT,DEBAMNT,CONVERT(int,DSTINDX),...
FROM dbo.[rahmani]
```

`DSTINDX` in the destination table is an `int` column (not null)

I am getting the following error message:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   
> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'G-PI100-5405-0000-UR' to data type   int.

The error is referencing the value `'G-PI100-5405-0000-UR'` in column `DSTINDX`.

I know it's because its `nvarchar` trying to convert to `int`, any ideas on how to correct this in the above statement?

Comment: Unless I am missing something, the issue is that the value `'G-PI100-5405-0000-UR'` is not a valid integer, hence the error.

Comment: The clue is in the error message you are trying to insert `'G-PI100-5405-0000-UR'` into a `INT` column. which fails. you probably have the order wrong in your select or insert statement.

Comment: How do you want it corrected? Change the type of `DSTINDX` to `nvarchar`, change the data to an `int` (which will mean data loss), or somehow split the data into multiple columns so that it can be inserted & preserved (sort of)?

Comment: I can't change the type in the destination table @alroc. I do not want to corrupt data loss. I originally tried to run a package import into the table and realized this was the error. I then imported it into a created table and wanted to do a select into so I could see the results of the data on a User Interface that this dataset is connected to.

Comment: could I use TRIM or SUBSTRING to cut the value to what the column in dbo.PM10100 table needs?

Comment: And what is the value that the column "needs"? It could be 100, 5405, 0, or any substring of any of those. Do we really need to guess how you want to convert that string to an integer?

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly saying: `CONVERT(int,DSTINDX)`

Why are you doing that? The source is obviously a string column, since it has at least one string value (which is the source of the error).

So, you need to either:

1. change the destination data type to match the source, and stop performing the convert
2. use a `CASE` expression to leave those values `NULL`
3. filter those rows out altogether

Examples of 2 & 3:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.flung(id INT, DSTINDX VARCHAR(32));

INSERT dbo.flung VALUES(1,'1'),(2,'2'),(3,'G-PI100-5405-0000-UR');

SELECT id, DSTINDX = CASE
  WHEN DSTINDX NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN DSTINDX END
FROM dbo.flung;

SELECT id, DSTINDX FROM dbo.flung WHERE DSTINDX NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%';
```

If you need to pull a substring of a string column and convert it to an `INT`, you're going to need to do a bit better than `CONVERT(INT` - SQL Server has no idea which parts of that string you're after, and you're going to have to construct a well-defined expression to extract that information.